# bison: empty pseudo variables

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm getting unexpected/missing output when running example 6 in [this howto](https://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html) (§4.3), using flex/bison instead of lex/yacc, in a cygwin environment.

I download and unpack the [example files](https://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-examples.tar.gz) from the download section. In the file example6.compile I substitute 'lex' with 'flex', otherwise keep it intact (the command yacc executes `exec '/usr/bin/bison' -y "$@"` on cygwin). Then I run example6.compile. It runs without errors, but with a few warnings (see appendix).
I then run example6, and input the example text:

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
        type hint;
};
```

The expected output is:

```
A zonefile name '/etc/bind/db.root' was encountered
Complete zone for '.' found
```

The actual output is:

```
A zonefile name '' was encountered
Complete zone for '' found
```

Why are the values of the pseudo variables missing?

**Appendix**

example6.compile:

```
flex example6.l
yacc --verbose --debug -d example6.y
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o example6
```

example6.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

zone                    return ZONETOK;
file                    return FILETOK;
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    yylval=strdup(yytext); return WORD;
[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+        yylval=strdup(yytext); return FILENAME;
\"                      return QUOTE;
\{                      return OBRACE;
\}                      return EBRACE;
;                       return SEMICOLON;
\n                      /* ignore EOL */;
[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;
%%
```

example6.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define YYSTYPE char *

int yydebug=0;

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
}

main()
{
        yyparse();
}

%}

%token WORD FILENAME QUOTE OBRACE EBRACE SEMICOLON ZONETOK FILETOK

%%

commands:
        |
        commands command SEMICOLON
        ;


command:
        zone_set
        ;

zone_set:
        ZONETOK quotedname zonecontent
        {
                printf("Complete zone for '%s' found\n",$2);
        }
        ;

zonecontent:
        OBRACE zonestatements EBRACE

quotedname:
        QUOTE FILENAME QUOTE
        {
                $$=$2;
        }
        ;

zonestatements:
        |
        zonestatements zonestatement SEMICOLON
        ;

zonestatement:
        statements
        |
        FILETOK quotedname
        {
                printf("A zonefile name '%s' was encountered\n", $2);
        }
        ;

block:
        OBRACE zonestatements EBRACE SEMICOLON
        ;

statements:
        | statements statement
        ;

statement: WORD | block | quotedname
```

Warnings when compiling:

```
example6.l: In function ‘yylex’:
example6.l:10:7: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    yylval=strdup(yytext); return WORD;
       ^
example6.l:11:7: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 [a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+        yylval=strdup(yytext); return FILENAME;
       ^
example6.y:19:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
example6.y: In function ‘main’:
example6.y:21:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyparse’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  yyparse();
  ^
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1164:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       yychar = yylex ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "warning" `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` should always be considered an error, since it (almost) always is.

In this case, what the error is telling you is that you are attempting to store a pointer (the return value of `strdup`, which is `char*`) into an integer (`yylval`).

Of course, `yylval` should not be an integer. In the C code in the prologue of your yacc/bison file, you include

```
#define YYSTYPE char *
```

But that line does not end up in the header file generated by yacc/bison. (If it did, the header file would also include the definition of `yyerror`, for example, which would lead to linkage problems since an executable can only have a single definition of a function.)

So you must also include that same `#define` in the prologue of your (f)lex input file, before you include the bison header file (because `YYSTYPE` is used in that file, for example to declare `yylval`). It is a little surprising that something which claims to be a HOW-TO for lex and yacc does not get this correct; you might want to consider submitting a bugfix.

Comment: Yes, that makes it work! NB! `#define YYSTYPE char *` must be placed above `#include "y.tab.h"` in the (f)lex file for it to work properly.

Comment: @matthiash: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I've added it now.